# Equivalent $C^1[0,1]$ norms

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\Vert f\Vert_a = \int_0^1 |f(x)|\,\text{d}x + \int_0^1 |f'(x)|\,\text{d}x$ and $\Vert f\Vert_b = |f(0)| + \int_0^1 |f'(x)|\,\text{d}x$. Show these norms are equivalent in $C^1[0,1]$.

My attempt: let $\beta_1 = \frac1{\max\{|f(0)|+|f'(\alpha_2)|, |f(\alpha_1)| + |f'(\alpha_2)|\}}$, where $\alpha_1, \alpha_2$ are picked such that $|f(\alpha_1)|=\int_0^1 |f(x)|\,\text{d}x$ and $|f'(\alpha_2)|= \int_0^1 |f'(x)|\,\text{d}x$. Then we have $\beta_1 \Vert f \Vert_b\leq \Vert f\Vert_a$.

I haven't tried to do the other inequality because I'm not sure about this one yet: the $\beta_{1,2}$ are supposed to be constants, yet I'm using the mean value theorem to obtain $|f(\alpha_1)|$ and $|f'(\alpha_2)|$. Is this a valid procedure? Is this even correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to show that there are constants independent of $f$ such that $K_1,K_2$ such that $\|f\|_a \le K_1 \|f\|_b$ and 
$\|f\|_b \le K_2 \|f\|_a$.

The key is $f(x) = f(0) + \int_0^x f'(t)dt$.

Since $|f(x)| \le |f(0)| + \int_0^x |f'(t)| dt  \le \|f\|_b$, integrating gives
$\int_0^1|f(t)|dt \le \|f\|_b$ and so
$\|f\|_a \le 2 \|f\|_b$.

Since $|f(0)| \le |f(x)|+ \int_0^x |f'(t)| dt \le |f(x)|+ \int_0^1 |f'(t)| dt $,
integrating gives
$|f(0)| \le \|f\|_a$ and so $\|f\|_b \le 2 \|f\|_a$.

Comment: Great idea! I wonder if that's the only way to do the exercise.

Comment: Dunno, but you need someway to connect $|f(0)|$ with $\int_0^1|f(t)|dt$, as such.

Comment: Please explain "integrating gives $\int_0^1|f(t)|dt \le \|f\|_b$" and also "integrating gives $|f(0)| \le \|f\|_a$". It's unclear what you're integrating and how you're getting that result.

Comment: @NicholasRoberts: Integrating the inequality $|f(x)| \le \|f\|_b$ from $0$ to $1$ gives $\int_0^1|f(x)|dx \le \| f \|_b$. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Yes, because in the defintion of the b-norm, there's already an integral present. So integrating both sides would result in two integrals on the right side of the inequality? That's why I'm confused.

Comment: @NicholasRoberts: If $c$ is a constant, then $\int_0^1 c dt = c$.

Comment: Oh, duh! Thank you :p